# Allowing any process to send a quit message

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have an issue with ties in a C/C++ MPI program that simulates playing a game across all the processes. If any process wins, including master, that process should tell all other processes to quit playing their game so the results can be sent to and totaled by master.

The problem is I sometimes get 1 or more processes on top of the winning process saying they won first. This results in a long hang (well over a minute in some cases) before finishing. I'm not sure if I'm handling the quit message situation properly between all processes.

**UPDATE**: This program is running on a single machine, not across a network. The machine is not on the internet.

**UPDATE 2**: I was able to substantially reduce the delay problem because of internal game code causing too many operations. I am still looking for interpretation of the way I am using Irecv/Isend to quit the processes.

**UPDATE 3**: Found my problem, shown in my answer.

Here is some code from my application to help.

```
int max_streak_length; // set in main from argv[], greater than 0
bool should_quit = false;

void checkMessages()
{
    static int recvFlag
    static bool msgBuff;
    static MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status status;

    // Are we already listening
    if( request )
    {
        // Test for message
        MPI_Test(&request, &recvFlag, &status);

        if( recvFlag )
        {
            if( status.MPI_TAG == TAG_QUIT )
                should_quit = true;
        }
    }

    // Start listening if we aren't
    if( !request )
        MPI_Irecv(&msgBuff, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, TAG_QUIT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
}

void processMaster(int numProcs) {
    double start = MPI_Wtime();
    Game game(max_streak_length);

    do
    {
        if( numProcs > 1 )
            checkMessages();
        game.play();
    } while( !should_quit && !game.is_game_over() );

    // Let other processes know they should stop, if I won
    if( !should_quit && game.is_game_over() )
    {
        cout << "Master wins " << MPI_Wtime() << endl;
        for( int pID = 1; numProcs > 1 && pID < numProcs; ++pID ) 
        {
            MPI_Request r;
            MPI_Isend(&should_quit, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, pID, TAG_QUIT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r);
        }
    }

    cout << "master quitting" << endl;
}

void processSlave(int numProcs, int rank) {
    Game game(max_streak_length);

    do
    {
        checkMessages();
        game.play();
    } while( !should_quit && !game.is_game_over() );

    // Let other processes know they should stop, if I won
    if( !should_quit && game.is_game_over() )
    {
        cout << rank << " wins " << MPI_Wtime() << endl;
        for( int pID = 0; pID < numProcs; ++pID ) 
        {
            if( pID == rank )
                continue;
            MPI_Request r;
            MPI_Isend(&should_quit, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, pID, TAG_QUIT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r);
        }
    }

    cout << rank << " quitting" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue. I no longer get the delays at all, and the issue was my game program logic itself. The processSlave for loop had been modified to have another condition `pID != rank` which broke the logic causing processes to be skipped when sending the TAG_QUIT message.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark/ethereal timing of 'win' packets?  How much delay between 'winners'?
Protocol allows multiple clients to say 'win', but does client assume they 'won', or await confirmation?

What is your protocol for messages?  You show 'TAG_QUIT' in a couple of places.  How about,

- child signals parent with 'Win'
- parent signals child with 'Confirm'
- winning child signals other children with 'Quit' (gloat)
- or, parent signals other children with 'Quit'
- losing child(ren) might signal 'Win' (failure due to race, delays)
- parent signals losing/late child with 'Lose' or 'Fail'

Comment: I updated my post to mention that I am only running this on a single machine, disconnected from the internet so I don't track packets. The delay is usually an increase of 100% over the time it took to report the first win. Any process exiting the do..while loop will assume they have won and only check locally if they won (no inter-process communication). I can handle the ties, but the delay is problematic.

Comment: I posted another update decreasing my delays substantially, however I am still looking for advice on the quit message system I am using.

Comment: Think about what messages you should send.  At a minimum, I think win, confirm and quit.  Plus you need to decide who sends the quit message.  You may want to record results from all children, so decide whether each child records their results, or the master records results.  How tight do you want signalling?  If you have several folks send 'win' now, they will each send quit to everyone.  a 'confirm' winner would allow the first winner to send the quit.